# Hard Drive disappears intermittently: SATA link down

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I really need some help from you guys, as I am struggling with this issue a lot..

So: I have 2 years old laptop Asus X555LAB, initially bought with pre-installed Windows 8, which was subsequently upgraded to Windows 10 and worked for 2 years without any problems. However, 2 weeks ago, laptop started to experience Blue Screens with message: **Critical Process Died**; that's all I could see really and Event Log didn't show much more. I tried to recover windows using Windows 10 Recovery Disc, then to reinstall completely, but to no avail --> same Blue Screen kept occurring.

Next, I downloaded Ubuntu image, and booted from DVD. Back then SSD was usually detectable by BIOS and I managed to play around with installations.

SSD started to show up and disappear as it wished to. When I am writing this post, I am on LiveDVD Ubuntu and can see on the launcher when sometimes partitions are being mounted and then disappear.

Before I will present my screens, I will explain what I've done so far to diagnose the culprit. So, I've got another laptop, Toshiba C660, with SSD as well, and in order to exclude hard drive failure possibility, I simply changed the SSDs: Toshiba detected foreign SSD in BIOS, whereas Asus didn't. So I opened the Asus, removed the SSD and the Ribbon, unplugged the black bit (I guess it is power supply) from the HHD Board, I put these things back to ensure that there are no looses anywhere, and surprisingly, SSD (Asus's drive) was detected in UEFI, and from there, I've managed to install fresh Ubuntu.

I was hoping that it solved the problem, until an hour ago, when the computer crashed again. Now I am unable to boot up the system and only UEFI interface shows up.

Screenshots: [dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4iSZ.png)

Smartmontools test didn't detect any problems at all with HDD, and personally I don't think that it is anything to do with Hard Drive, as I was able to install Linux on this hard drive using Toshiba Laptop, and errors included in screenshots above were not present.

Log: [Smartmontools](https://pastebin.com/PvPQnuiz)

Usually, the following errors come up. From what I read, it seems to be power-supply-related issue, but I am not capable of diagnosing the cause by myself.

```
[Fri Jun  9 18:25:06 2017] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jun  9 18:25:06 2017] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[Fri Jun  9 18:25:06 2017] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[Fri Jun  9 18:25:06 2017] ata1: hard resetting link
[Fri Jun  9 18:25:06 2017] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 320)
```

When partitions show up, **dmesg -T** outputs the following:

```
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:45 2017] ata1: EH complete
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: hard resetting link
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1.00: ATA-9: SanDisk SDSSDA120G, Z22000RL, max UDMA/133
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1.00: 234441648 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] ata1: EH complete
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SanDisk SDSSDA12 00RL PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/112 GiB)
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 sdb5
[Fri Jun  9 18:31:52 2017] sd 0:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

**sudo parted -l** (only when SSD kicks in)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SanDisk SDSSDA12 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:
```

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000MB  999MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      1000MB  4000MB  3000MB  linux-swap(v1)
 3      4000MB  44.0GB  40.0GB  ext4
 4      44.0GB  59.0GB  15.0GB  ext4
 5      59.0GB  120GB   61.0GB  ext4

Model: MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8E2 S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sr0: 1554MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/2048B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      7389kB  9880kB  2490kB               EFI

The problem is that majority of information refers to PC not laptops. But I was thinking about buying HHD Board or the Ribbon, as perhaps these two failed (no clue how they could but anyway).

I will appreciate any help, and advice whether to buy the HDD Board or Ribbon, or perhaps the issue is somewhere else.

Best regards

---

Thanks for your prompt reply @psusi.

Do you mean to plug in different charger right? I did that, to no avail. Not sure though if it is okay to plug in charger from another brand (Toshiba's charger's output parameters differ slightly)

Does SATA cable refer to this white [ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4iSZ.png) and SATA controller to the [HDD Board](https://pastebin.com/PvPQnuiz)?

Best regards

UPDATE1: I've noticed that **dmesg -T** outputs the following errors immediately when I plug in charger and plug off:

```
[Fri Jun  9 20:17:57 2017] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
[Fri Jun  9 20:17:57 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
[Fri Jun  9 20:20:50 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
[Fri Jun  9 20:21:19 2017] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
[Fri Jun  9 20:21:20 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
[Fri Jun  9 20:21:36 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
[Fri Jun  9 20:21:42 2017] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
[Fri Jun  9 20:21:43 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
[Fri Jun  9 20:22:56 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
[Fri Jun  9 20:23:03 2017] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
[Fri Jun  9 20:23:03 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
```

UPDATE2: I've disassembled HDD Controller and the ribbon, attached again, and system loaded. Don't know what is going on really.

[dmesg -T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4iSZ.png)

UPDATE3:

Today, **dmesg -T** outputs again ata1 errors. It returned when I plugged in a device into USB port.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgUBW.png)

Comment: HDD Board: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-HDD-Hard-Drive-Board-For-Asus-K555-R556L-X553M-X555L-X555LD-Rev-3-3-/132158643699?autorefresh=true

Ribbon: https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/LvvDqnLlvNYW2Uif.medium

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://www.systutorials.com/qa/1651/wrong-messages-unrecovdata-badcrc-failed-command-fpdma-queued

Answer (score 1):

Try supplying the drive with power from another power supply to rule that out.  Otherwise it is either the SATA cable, which is easy enough to replace, or the SATA controller, which is built into the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Any ideas on what might be the issue? It is a laptop, not desktop PC, so there is no SATA cables, instead something like a SATA connector which connects the motherboard and the SSD, and this flat ribbon, but correct me please if I'm wrong.

Errors still appear, and according to this source: [The Analysis of Drive Issues](https://wiki.lime-technology.com/The_Analysis_of_Drive_Issues#Drive_interface_issue_.234) it is something to do with an inadequate power supply. But the link refers to PC, where SATA cable can be replaced.

I don't want to keep posting to myself, I'm just giving new information on what's going on so perhaps somebody will be able to tell me what exactly should be replaced to solve this.

Currently, laptop works but crashes from time to time, and **dmesg -T** classically outputs same errors:

```
[Sun Jun 11 18:56:49 2017] ata1: EH complete
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:40 2017] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:40 2017] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:40 2017] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:40 2017] ata1: hard resetting link
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:41 2017] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:46 2017] ata1: hard resetting link
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:46 2017] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:46 2017] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[Sun Jun 11 19:05:46 2017] ata1: EH complete
```

Additionally, other weird things I've noticed so far are:

1. Airplane diode lights on when WiFi works (kind of reversed functioning)
2. These lines come up when I plug in the charger:

```
[Sun Jun 11 17:14:18 2017] asus_wmi: Unknown key cf pressed
[Sun Jun 11 17:14:18 2017] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: Unsupported event [0x84]
```

Best regards

Comment: I think I have got the exact same error - did you figure it out in the meantime?